# how can I override the Chakra-UI button theme when I am in an 'isLoading' state?

Tags: button, chakra-ui

This is my current override which works fine, but when I pass an isLoading prop, the theme is far too light.

```
solid: {
      bgGradient: "linear(to-r, primary.600, primary.500)",
      color: "white",
      _active: {},
      _hover: {
        transform: "scale(0.98)",
        bgGradient: "linear(to-r, primary.500, primary.400)",
      },
      _focus: {},
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `_loading` key and set `opacity` to 1

```
solid: {
      bgGradient: "linear(to-r, primary.600, primary.500)",
      color: "white",
      _active: {},
      _hover: {
        transform: "scale(0.98)",
        bgGradient: "linear(to-r, primary.500, primary.400)",
      },
      _focus: {},
      _loading: { opacity: 1 }
    },
```